# Regular expression help for arecord command output

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

How do I get the card number and device number alone from this string by using a regular expression to parse it?

Here's the string

```
 ~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: usb device [usb device], device 0: Audio [Audio Input]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I need to parse the "card 0" and "device 0". I just need the values 0,0

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using _Mathematica_ for this task? What code have you tried?

Comment: To all, I don't see how closing this as needing more info can be justified when it has an accepted answer.

Comment: FWIW: you can execute shell commands from within *Mathematica*: `ReadList["!arecord -l", "String"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions.

```
text = 
"~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: usb device [usb device], device 0: Audio [Audio Input]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0"

StringCases[text, {"card" | "device"} ~~ Whitespace ~~ d : (DigitCharacter ..) -> d]
```

> `{"0", "0"}`